# Using selenium-client to click a button that is part of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

Hey, this should be pretty simple, but it's causing me a lot of grief! I have lots of buttons like this:

```
<form class="general" method="post" action="/password">
  <div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;">
    <input type="hidden" value="Yg4EweyWwXO8RAF9nd3RZKNmQw8Yk+f2vefLQ/IENyg=" name="authenticity_token"/>
  </div>
   <fieldset>
      <ol>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="submit save">
    <span class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit"/>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

so, the question is... how do I click the button?

I should point out that I am not using Webrat with selenium, just straight up selenium. I've tried "selenium.click"-ing just about everything I can think of. It seems that the click method want's an ID, but I don't know what ID to give it...

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selenium.click("//input[@name='commit' and @value='#{button}']")
```

(told you it was simple)

Comment: All the answers here are basically getting at the same thing. Thanks fot the responses, this is what I'm currently using in to test my app.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following locator:

```
css=form.general input[type=submit]
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing some obvious reason why you can't use this but why not use:

```
name=commit
```

Comment: because there are several buttons on any given page.

Comment: Okay. the other solutions will all click the first button though, so this would do the same and is arguably the simplest. If you want to click a specific button you could use something like `xpath=/descendant::input[@name='commit'][1]` where 1 is the index of the button you want to click.